# I can't change my skin

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

When I try to change my skin, I don't see a box that says "equip". So, how do I change my skin? I imported this skin pack, is that the problem? I have never had a problem with an imported skin pack until today.

[image: this is what I see when I try to equip a skin]

Answer (score 0):

There may be a problem with the skin pack you downloaded that bugged the equip button. I suggest you delete the skin pack.